# Is there an easy way to quickly prove (or memorize) inverse trig formulas such as $ \arcsin(a) = \arctan(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}) $?

Tags: trigonometry

> Is there an easy way to quickly prove these formulas?
>
> If not, is there any easy mnemonic way to memorize them fast?

$$\begin{align}
\arcsin(a) &= \arctan\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right) \\[4pt]
\arccos(a) &= \operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right) \\[4pt]
\arctan(a) = \arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right) &= \arccos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right) = \operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) \\[4pt]
\operatorname{arccot}(a) &= \arccos\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\right)
\end{align}$$

P.S. Wikipedia desribes it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions)

[image]

Comment: remember $\tan=\dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$ and $sin^2+cos^2=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first one draw a right angled triangle as below.[image]

Now $\sin x = a \implies x = \sin^{-1}a = \tan^{-1}\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$

Do similarly for the other cases.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the last one, if $\theta=\operatorname{arccot}(a)$ then $a=\cot\theta,$

so $a^2+1=\left(\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)^2=\dfrac1{\sin^2\theta}=\dfrac1{1-\cos^2\theta}.$

Can you take it from here?

The others are similar.